# Adding custom scrollbars to vuetify data tables

Tags: vue.js, datatable, scrollbar, vuetify.js

I am trying to add `perfect-scrollbar` to vuetify's data tables. So I have to wrap the data table inside the `perfect-scrollbar` component like this -

```
<perfect-scrollbar>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="data" />
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

The problem is that its also wrapping the data-table footer. I want to wrap only the data of table within `perfect-scrollbar` component. So that only data is scrollable and footer remains there.

Now it looks like this -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need to use `perfect-scrollbar` here. 
You just set the height to `v-data-table`. Then the component automatically sets the scroll bar.

As the example,

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="data" height="200px"/>
```

Try with it.

Comment: I want to use custom scrollbars